# Derivation of Newton's Decrement

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Sorry for posting such a simple question but I'd like to know if somebody knows a derivation of Newton's Decrement? A few hours of googling
hasn't led to an answer(mostly we just define it without derivation I guess see below) so that I would like to borrow your knowledge.

### Definition of Newton's Decrement

For instance,

- [Page 486 of Professor Boyd's Convex Optimisation book](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/)
- Some Lecture notes: [Eq 7.1](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Ecmcaram/EE381V_2012F/Lecture_7_Scribe_Notes.final.pdf) / [slide 2](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eyuying/Courses/CS870_2012/July10_12.pdf) / [slide 3](https://stateofther.github.io/finistR2018/files/newton_method.pdf)

define Newton's decrement as
$$
\lambda(x) = \Big( \nabla f(x)^{T} \nabla^{2} f(x)^{-1} \nabla f(x) \Big)^{1/2}
$$
And this quantity normally is being used as a stopping condition of the Newton's Method.

Comment: Could you be more precise? Is the Newton's Decrement the step of the Newton's Method to minimize functions?

Comment: @DanielCunha, thank you for your prompt response and sorry for the lack of description, let me edit my question!

Comment: It seems to measure how much the objective-function decreases after each step of the Newton's Method

Comment: Yeah, I get that the Newton's decrement is basically the Euclidean norm under Hessian, right? So that it measures the distance or length of your displacement. But still there shouldn't be some derivation behind the scene?

Comment: sorry, considering that it's been used as a stopping condition. I am getting to think that the definition and interpretation suffice..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to minimize $f(\mathbf{x})$. Firstly, we consider its second-order truncated Taylor series:

$$f(\mathbf{x}) \approx \hat{f}(\mathbf{x})= f(\mathbf{x_0}) + [\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}]^T\,\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0}) + \frac{1}{2}\,[\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}]^T\,\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})\,[\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}]$$

Considering the Hessian Matrix $\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})$ is positve-definite, $\hat{f}(\mathbf{x})$ can be easily minimized:

$$\frac{\partial \hat{f}(\mathbf{x^*})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \nabla f(\mathbf{x_0}) + \nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})\,[\mathbf{x^*}-\mathbf{x_0}] = \mathbf{0} \Rightarrow \mathbf{x^*} = \mathbf{x_0} - \nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})^{-1}\,\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0})$$

So we have the minimized value:

$$\hat{f}(\mathbf{x^*})= f(\mathbf{x_0}) - [\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})^{-1}\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0})]^T\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0}) + \frac{1}{2}[\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})^{-1}\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0})]^T\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})[ \nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})^{-1}\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0})]$$

So the decrement on the approximation $\hat{f}(\mathbf{x})$ is given by:

$$f(\mathbf{x_0})-\hat{f}(\mathbf{x^*}) = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}\,\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0})^T\,\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})^{-1}\,\nabla f(\mathbf{x_0})}$$

(A Hessian Matrix is always symmetric for "well behaved" functions)

Answer (score 1):

## This is quite trivial

Considering that through a series of Reidemeister moves we find that

$$\forall \chi \in \mathbb{R} \forall f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\exists \lambda\Big[\nabla f(\chi)=\Big(\frac{\lambda^2(\chi)}{\nabla^2f^{-1}(\chi)\nabla f(\chi)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{T}}\Big]$$

Being a direct variant of the Axiom of Cacatus, we find through a series of inverted hyperoperations that

$$\lambda(\chi)=\sqrt{\nabla f(\chi)^T\nabla^2 f^{-1}(\chi)\nabla f(\chi)}$$

$$\mathbb{Q}\exists\mathfrak{D}$$

This is an example of PBI (proof by intimidation).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the explanation from a surprising angle with me! I didn't expect that the knot theory can help to explain the newton's decrement!

Comment: @Rowing0914 Always at your service, sire.

Comment: iI would be glad if someone could explain further